# Black folder icons after update

Tags: updates, icons

I am on Ubuntu 19.10. After installing some updates, the folder icons have turned black. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the colour of the folder icon is black or is it just a black square?  In the first case check if you haven't accidentally changed your icon theme.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now using a different icon theme. The easiest way I know to check and change is to install Gnome Tweaks.  Then go to the Appearance tab and try changing the Icons theme.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, your icons did not turn black. But indeed, they are not anymore orange, but gray. That is a deliberate change by the Ubuntu developers in the Yaru theme, the theme used by the Ubuntu desktop.